# Do I have to manually enable a Postgres extension despite using doctrine?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, postgis

I'm using Symfony3. Symfony3 comes with doctrine. After I set up everything I get some errors caliming there's something missing in my database. Turns out I have to enable my postgres extension (PostGIS) by doing:

```
psql -d yourdatabase -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
psql -d yourdatabase -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;"
```

So it does work now but I did that manually and I can't really predict the influence it has on doctrines database manipulation mechanics.

So my question is: Is it okay to manually activate the extension like I did it? And can I somehow also kind of delegate this to doctrine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly ok and it's the only way to do it. It's your responsibility to create install and configure your DBMS, and to create the database and to add the extensions you'll use.

You should probably use a tool like Docker or Chef to automate the creation of the environment.

Alternatively, you can create your own Symfony command that will execute those queries. It's easy to copy and adapt the code of the Symfony's `doctrine:database:create` command to automate this. The original code can be found here: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Command/CreateDatabaseDoctrineCommand.php